# Use time condition with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to make an request with a condition of time. I would like something like that:

```
Model.where{'updated_at > updated_at + 10.minutes'}
```

Of course this previous code is not working.

I didn't find any solution of this problem until now.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: You're passing a block to `where` instead passing the argument in as a method argument like `where('updated_at > updated_at + 10.minutes')`, is using a block with `where` like that actually possible?

Comment: I got a solution that you can see below. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it like this:

```
Model.where{updated_at < DateTime.now - 10.minutes}
```